# Multiple issues in firefox but works properly in chrome with no single issue

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, form-data, superagent

I am having multiple issues with firefox but not in chrome.

**1) issue in TypeError: response.body is null.**

**2) while uploading for images i get TypeError: Argument 1 of FormData.constructor does not implement interface HTMLFormElement.**

The code where issue is shown are

for number 1 issue (I have used superagent for this)

```
  search( query='Ganesh Chowk' ){
    let url = "/api/v1/rental/?place__startswith="+encodeURIComponent(query);
    Request.get(url).then((response) => {
    if (response) {
        this.setState({
            place:response.body.objects,
        });
    } else {
        this.setState({
            place: [],
        });
    }
});
```

**for 2nd issue**

```
  let image = [];
 class RenderPhotos extends React.Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
        this.state = {
            files: []
        };
    }

    onDrop(files) {
      console.log('Received files: ', files);
      this.setState({
          files: files
      });

    image = new FormData(files);
    $.each(files,function(i,file){
      image.append('image',file);
    });

    }
```

Why this code is working on chrome and not in firefox? What should be changed for this code to work in all browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding Error 2: If a [parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData) is passed to the `FormData` constructor it must be a HTML `<Form>` element which does not seem to be the case in your code. So simply drop the param:

```
image = new FormData();
```

**Update:**

Regarding error 1: As you found out yourself the request needs an accept header `application/json`. Due to differences of Chrome and Firefox default accept headers, the server seems to return a json payload for Chrome and not for Firefox. Anyway the explicit header resolves that issue.

Comment: It worked like a charm. Do you know the cause of first issue?

Comment: @Milan no. Maybe you can detect the cause if you compare the HTTP request and response in the network dev tools when you run in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Thanks i will diagnose the issue.

Comment: I set my header as set('Accept', 'application/json') and it is working in firefox but dont know why without this firefox is throwing error. Can you please post this for issue 1 so i can mark this as answered.

Comment: @milan great. Added your findings to the answer